# Unlinking objects make them disappear entirely. Why?

Tags: linked-data

I've used Blender for years, but one thing that continually baffles me is when objects are "linked." Frequently, when I "unlink" a group of objects, they disappear entirely from the project. How did that happen? What were they linked to? And where did they go? I didn't delete anything, only unlinked.

This usually happens when I import a 3rd-party product, and when I try to work with it linking weirdness happens. Can someone enlighten me? Thanks. Blender 3.4.1, Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

Linking objects into a scene is a form of virtual import, where instead of copying elements from an external source into your scene, you only make a "link" that reads the content from the external source.
It's like in your file explorer when you make a shortcut to a file instead of copying it.

That's why, unlinking basically deletes whatever you unlinked from your scene. It doesn't delete the source of the link, it just removes its presence from your scene.

To know what is the source of a link, you can switch your Outliner's Display Mode to `Blender File` and look at the bottom of your file (or the `Libraries` category):

[image: linked data]

You can see either the absolute path of the source file, or its relative path from your current .blend.

It is good to know that it is possible to pack the source file of a link into the .blend file. So sometimes you will see a path to a .blend file that doesn't exist. To fix that, go to the menu File > External Data > Unpack Linked Libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I'm aware of linking to external files, and I do it all the time, but I frequently encounter situations where the "linked" file is not linked to an external resource, nevertheless it will disappear when "unlinked." This makes me think there's some sort of internal linking I'm not familiar with. Thanks again.